subfloor preparation for top nail 5/16th red oak flooring
This is a specific question about 5/16" top-down red oak flooring. The manufacturer is likely Lebanon Oak Flooring, and this is a common material in the San Francisco Bay Area. It is not tongue & groove - it is S4S. There's a wealth of information at the manufacturer site https://www.lebanonoak.com, and I suspect most flooring companies are supplied by Tom Duffy Flooring, a regional wholesaler.
My subfloor is not flat. I have read about a few basic approaches:

Subfloor patch and leveling compound, such as the one made by DAP. This sounds good but I'm not sure if the compound will stay flexible when top nailing down the flooring.

Self leveler. This sounds like concrete and too brittle to handle a lot of nails drive through it into the subfloor.

Home brew approaches like shingles, tar paper, felt, and even cardboard. Various lengths are cut to create an "upside down wedding cake" to fill in dips. These seem reasonable to me (other than tar paper potentially melting during sanding and off-gassing VOCs).

Luoan plywood or other thin plywoods to even out the dips.


Question. Given the it appears common to use thin foil-like or paper-like materials, how about using aluminum flashing in the same way? It has the advantage of water and corrosion resistance - paper, cardboard, and thin plywood will swell and then shrink if there's any water intrusion.

Aluminum is a bad idea due to galvanic corrosion: steel nails will rust. I have read some folks using shingles. Likely a very bad idea, the tar will offgas VoC into your home and there may also be antifungals. Mapai's website actually is explicit that there's a limit to how deep self leveler should be applied, and suggests EPS/XPS for the majority of your leveling. https://www.mapei.com/ca/en-ca/training-and-technical-service/tech-talk-blog/detail/mapei-blog/2022/03/01/level-subfloor
